# Printing a paginated PDF w/ NSPrintOperation from a subclass of NSDocument, results in duplicate squished image over multiple pages

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf, printing, nsprintoperation

So I have tried a couple routes here, but there always seems to be a trade off.

What I have is a vertically long PDF (Contained within a subclass of `NSDocument`), and for example I will be using a screenshot of a16z.  This is my current result of printing then choosing the "Save to PDF" option.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/02u3j8pbw1kne91/Untitled.pdf?dl=0

There are two issues with this:
1) The image seems to be stretched vertically a little bit
2) When I actually make a physical print, it only grabs the bottom left corner, and only part of the pdf as well:
[image]

So here is the pertinent code (At least I believe, there could be more in other layers but I've mostly been playing around here):

```
   EditorPrintView *offscreenView = [[EditorPrintView alloc] initWithFrame:[self canvasRect] withImageDoc:self withBackgroundColor:[self backgroundColor]];

   NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [self printInfo];
   [printInfo setVerticalPagination:NSAutoPagination];
   [printInfo setPaperSize:NSMakeSize[self canvasRect].size.width , ([self canvasRect].size.height+[[self printInfo] topMargin] + [[self printInfo] bottomMargin]))];
   [self setPrintInfo:printInfo];

   NSPrintOperation *op = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:offscreenView
                                                         printInfo:printInfo];
   [op runOperationModalForWindow:[[EditorWindowController sharedWindowController] window]
                                 delegate:self
                         didRunSelector:@selector(printOperationDidRun:success:contextInfo:)
                             contextInfo:nil];
```

Now here's where things get funky.

I have been making changes to the `paperSize` with `NSMakeSize[self canvasRect].size.width , ([self canvasRect].size.height+[[self printInfo] topMargin] + [[self printInfo] bottomMargin]))` to produce different results with the printing.

Here have been my experiments:
1) If I do not set the `paperSize` at all, the pdf actually paginates correctly: 
[image]
The number of pages is correct, *but*, the content is incorrect.  Each page gets the entire image squished into one page.
2) If I set the `paperSize` to be the size of the image, 2 pages get produced.  One page with the correct size (the page size is huge):
[image]
, and then another page with the entire image squished into the vertical size of the margins of the page:
[image]

3) So naturally, I decided to go with the code I have now, and added the margins when I set `paperSize`.

This results in the one page pdf that I linked initially-- but again, it seems to be stretched vertically, and also doesn't actually print correctly

Knowing all of this, I believe that I do *not* want to mess with the `paperSize` so I can maintain the correct pagination, and maintain a normal paper size.

I believe that perhaps I am doing something wrong with the `NSView` that I am supplying.  Those with a keen eye would see that I have a subclassed `NSView` called `EditorPrintView`.  Here is the `-drawRect` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect 
{
   if ( (_editorDoc) && (_backgroundColor) )
   {
      NSGraphicsContext* theContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
      if ( [theContext isDrawingToScreen] == NO ) 
      {
         [theContext saveGraphicsState];

         ImageDocumentRenderer* renderer = [ImageDocumentRenderer pixelRenderForDocumentData:_editorDoc.docData andDownsample:NO];
         CGLayerRef cgLayer = [renderer createPrinterFriendlyCGLayerWithContext:(CGContextRef)[theContext graphicsPort] andBackgroundColor:_backgroundColor];

         CGContextDrawLayerInRect((CGContextRef)[theContext graphicsPort], rect, cgLayer);
         [theContext restoreGraphicsState];
         CGLayerRelease(cgLayer);
      }
      else
      {
         NSLog(@"EditorPrintView drawRect - called for drawing onpo [ screen, should only be used for printing");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      NSLog(@"EditorPrintView drawRect - editordocument and/or background color never set, NOT DRAWING ANYTHING");
   }
}
```

This is where the real wall comes up, because I have no idea how to debug CGContext, and the initial engineer is gone from the company so I can't ask anybody.  Are there any red flags anybody can see with how I am drawing my `NSView`?

I know this is a long one, so cheers in advance for your time reading :)